# Is certificate authorization via HTTPS possible?

Tags: automation, lets-encrypt

I am using the Let's Encrypt IIS client from https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple to generate a certificate for a server. Since the certificate is only valid for three months, I want it to auto-renew.

But the server for which I need that auto-renewing certificate is only bound to https:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com:443 and smtp:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com:25.
Both http:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com:80 and ftp:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com:21 point to a different server.

As you may have guessed, the error that is now thrown during the process is "The ACME server was probably unable to reach http:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com:80/.well-known/acme-challenge/abcdefgh...xyz".

It is completely clear to me why, but I can't fix it, because http:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com has to point to the other server. If the ACME server would try https:||mysubdomain.mydomain.com:443/.well-known/acme-challenge/abcdefgh...xyz, but ignore any certificate issue, he would successfully find the challenge.

Is there anything I can do, any feature I have overlooked, that would help me to get automated renewal working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options:

### `http-01`

Redirect `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*` to `https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*`, Boulder  will happily follow any such redirect and ignore the provided certificate. That's the most simple way if you have access to the other server and can configure that redirect. It's a permanent redirect that you don't have to adjust, it'll be just fine every three months.

The option to use HTTPS directly has been removed due to security issues with some popular server software that uses the first host defined if some other virtual host doesn't define any HTTP host, which might lead to wrong issuances in multi-user environments aka shared hosting.

### `tls-sni-01`

If you want to use just port `443`, you can use another challenge type called `tls-sni-01`. But I think there's no client for Windows available yet that supports that challenge type.

### `dns-01`

If you have control over the DNS via a simple API, you could also use the DNS challenge, it's completely independent of the port you can use.

Comment: After the other server's maintainer has declined my request of a redirection rule, I have chosen option 4 and requested a commercial certificate (will be valid for three years, I think). Let's see what my options are three years from now.

Comment: I'm running the same setup, :80 and :443 does not point to same site.
So the removal of https-verification is the reason my certificate suddenly have failed to be renewed.

Comment: Strange, this oonly kicked in this renewal cycle, but anyway, I fixed it with an alias from one site to the other.